# Custom popup not moving with the map view

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to place the information to the map annotation with custom callout.

But the popup on the map is not movable, it's static.

Here is the code for the `didSelectAnnotationView`:

```
if(![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    CGSize  calloutSize = CGSizeMake(180, 106);
    paintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x-60, view.frame.origin.y-110, calloutSize.width, calloutSize.height)];

    [paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [paintView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    paintView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_popup.png"]];


    lblUsername = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 5, 100, 20)];
    lblUsername.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblUsername.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    //lblName.numberOfLines=0;
    [lblUsername setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:16]];
    lblUsername.lineBreakMode= NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:144/255.0 green:44/255.0 blue:123/255.0 alpha:1];
    lblUsername.text =[arrUserName objectAtIndex:nameInd];
    [paintView addSubview:lblUsername];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(selectAdd)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, 40, 40);
    [view addSubview:button];

    [view addSubview:paintView];
}
```

Comment: So, what's your problem? What do you mean by "fix"ing the pop-up? Is it broken?

Comment: problem is that custome popup not movable with mkmapview move.